# How to hide element of a webpage from webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have no idea about javascript :). I am trying to load a page in my webview in android, and when that page loads, a particular image in the webpage must be hidden.
  This is my following code

```
private class MWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        //url.
      //  String javascript="javascript: document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello "+user+"!';";
        String javascriptM="javascript: document.getElementById('logo').style.visibility = 'hidden'; ";
        view.loadUrl(javascriptM);
        Log.d("++++++++","+++++++");
    }
}
```

So the thing is It is loading the page again with

> hidden

written and nothing else on webpage. What do I need to do so that I can only hide that particular image with id "logo" and load rest of the page ? 
Thanks much :)

Answer (score 1):

change visiblity to display and hidden to none to hide it in your view

eg : document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'none';

Hope this will solve your problem